# How to restore the user postgres?

Tags: linux, users, postgresql

In the second answer in this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/110154/whats-the-default-superuser-username-password-for-postgres-after-a-new-install) is a warning about changing the UNIX password for "postgres".
I have already changed the password for "postgres".
How could I restore the initially state of the user "postgres"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comments in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/325596/97710) suggest, just edit the file `/etc/shadow` **as root** (e.g. run `sudo nano /etc/shadow` in a terminal) and replace the hashed password in `postgres`'s line with `*`.

(If you don't have that line or that file, it'd be interesting to know which Linux distribution and `nsswitch` settings you use.)

Comment: I have overlooked the comments.